# prettyphoto gallery in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, prettyphoto

I'm pretty new to web programming and was supposed to make a gallery with a slideshow.

I have done that but I am having some problems,  and I can't exactly figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I created two galleries but I ended up having all the pictures in both galleries. In gallery one I have 28 pics while in gallery two I have around 26...

But I end up having 54 in both!

Here is a part of my code... please look and try to help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Gallery 1

```
<a href="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/12185417_1008152529227346_4800719360163385651_o__1470835937_92.221.124.15.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1]"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1384" style="display: none;" src="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/12185417_1008152529227346_4800719360163385651_o__1470835937_92.221.124.15-300x200.jpg" alt="12185417_1008152529227346_4800719360163385651_o__1470835937_92.221.124.15" width="300" height="200" /></a>
<a href="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/12194647_1008152062560726_5009168883409523955_o__1470835962_92.221.124.15.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1]"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1385" style="display: none;" src="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/12194647_1008152062560726_5009168883409523955_o__1470835962_92.221.124.15-300x200.jpg" alt="12194647_1008152062560726_5009168883409523955_o__1470835962_92.221.124.15" width="300" height="200" /></a>
```

Gallery 2

```
<a href="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/11059666_957655130943753_8621478213892114678_o__1470836756_92.221.124.15.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[2]"><img class="alignnone wp-image-1353" style="display: none;" src="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/11059666_957655130943753_8621478213892114678_o__1470836756_92.221.124.15-300x163.jpg" alt="11059666_957655130943753_8621478213892114678_o__1470836756_92.221.124.15" width="300" height="163" /></a>
<a href="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/11223546_957650610944205_3563120639042996514_o__1470836767_92.221.124.15.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[2]"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-1354" style="display: none;" src="http://www.alfalahss.no/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/11223546_957650610944205_3563120639042996514_o__1470836767_92.221.124.15-300x197.jpg" alt="11223546_957650610944205_3563120639042996514_o__1470836767_92.221.124.15" width="300" height="197" /></a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is supposed to be showing, I'm assuming as this is a Wordpress plugin, there must be some settings that aren't set correctly? Or maybe you're using shortcodes to show ALL photos in both?

Comment: i dont think there is a problem with settings as everything works fine except fr this problem..m not using shortcode aswell...as u can see in the rel tag i have named the galleries one and two...bt somhow its not working as it is supposed to...any suggestions??

Comment: No idea, is there any way you can provide links to show us what's happening?